# ssh connection to Vagrant virtual machine using Ansible fails

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ansible

I'm new to Ansible.I set-up an Ubuntu virtual machine using Vagrant. I'm able to ssh into the machine using ssh vagrant@172.16.23.228. I have created an ssh key with the same password as the vm, added it to the agent and specified the path in my hosts file.

After following the instructions [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_getting_started.html) I started to receive the following errors, when running this command (ansible all --inventory-file=hosts.ini --module-name ping -u vagrant -vvvv):

Not sure what I'm missing from my set-up, what else I need to check?

```
<172.16.23.228> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: vagrant
<172.16.23.228> REMOTE_MODULE ping
<172.16.23.228> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o     ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/Users/user/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" - o Port=22 -o IdentityFile="~Users/user/.ssh/onemachine_rsa" -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=vagrant -o ConnectTimeout=10 172.16.23.228 /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p     $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1451080871.59-247915080664557 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1451080871.59-247915080664557 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1451080871.59-247915080664557'
172.16.23.228 | FAILED => SSH Error: tilde_expand_filename: No such user Users
while connecting to 172.16.23.228:22
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH  debug output to help diagnose the issue.

My hosts file looks like: 
[testserver]
172.16.23.228 ansible_ssh_port=22 ansible_ssh_user=vagrant    ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~Users/user/.ssh/onemachine_rsa
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path to your `ansible_ssh_private_key_file` is incorrect. Try `ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/onemachine_rsa` instead. The tilde in this case expands to the home directory of your user on the local machine you're running ansible from.

Comment: Hi @Dave, I couldn't get this to work with an SSH key. The only way I was able to get it to work was using the vagrant key file. /Users/me/Documents/Vagrant/one/.vagrant/machines/default/vmware_fusion/private_key

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing can work, but I highly recommend using the built-in [Ansible provisioner](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/ansible.html) in Vagrant. It will make your life easier and improve your Vagrant skills at the same time. And if you need to execute any shell scripts, use the [shell provisioner](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html).

Answer (score 1):

Providing this answer for the benefit of those, like me, who arrive later at the party. Latest Vagrant installations install a private key in a local directory instead of using the admittedly insecure private key for every VM. You'll have to create an ansible_hosts file like this one:

```
[vagrantboxes]
jessie ansible_ssh_port=2222 ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1

[vagrantboxes:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=vagrant
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
```

Where the key is the last line, which provides a path to the actual private key used in the virtual machine that has been started up from this particular directory.

Comment: thank you!   you saved me a lot of time and now I'll go back and read more ansible documentation regarding vars.  
I moved all variables under [bagrantboxes:vars] so everything that has to do with vagrant stays under 1 single place
Tnx again!